# window.onload and document.ready : execution order in case specified multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

We all know that we can use document.ready many times and they will be executed one by one in the order as mentioned in script.

Also we know that we can use window.onload only once.

The question here is, what will happen if we use window.onload ? is this error or the first one will be executed and rest are ignored or last one will be executed and rest are ignored?

Comment: @AlexChar: i am not asking for the difference. I have checked and did not get any post so thats why posted.

Comment: Do you mean `$(document).read(fn)` when you talk about `document.ready`?

Comment: This would be very easy to test yourself

Comment: @DanielSchmidt: yes. its $(document).ready()

Comment: @Parashuram The question is unclear, can you add example code. `what will happen if we use window.onload ?` you mean more than once, right?

Comment: @Tushar: Yes.In that case what ill happen is the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/ouk7aatj/

the last onload will be fired and all previous `onload` statements will be ignored

```
window.onload= function() {
  alert("Onload 1");
};

window.onload= function() {
  alert("Onload 2");
};
```

---

```
var i = 0;

window.onload= function() {
     i = 10;
  alert(i);
};

window.onload= function() {
    i++
  alert(i);
};
```

Output : 1

You can attach a function to the window.onload event listener like so if you want it to "act" the same as document.ready

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/ouk7aatj/1/

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (){
    alert('Function #1');
});

window.addEventListener('load', function (){
    alert('Function #2');
});
```

Comment: Basically I think it attached an event to the dom ready event. and then fires each ready handler you have first come first serve (top to bottom). This can be quite useful. This means you don't have to have 1 master document.ready function which will run all your Javascript starters and event listeners. Example you could have a dropdown plugin and a file plugin, you can add a `document.ready` function to both and not worry about calling them in your `main` js file. The reason the window.onload is only fired once however take a look at my updated code

Comment: The old-ish way `window.onload = ( typeof window.onload !== 'function' ? myFunc : function() { window.onload(); myFunc(); } )`

Answer (score 2):

At first, there are fundamental differences between `$(document).ready(...)` and `window.onload`. The first one occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, the native `onload` occurs when the window has loaded, meaning resources (images, ...) are also loaded.

Take the following example:

```
window.onload = function () { console.log(1); }
window.onload = function () { console.log(2); }
```

Meaning the first function gets overwritten by pointing to the second function. The output will be `2` in your console, and `console.log(1)` will never be executed.

Your jQuery on the other hand:

```
$(document).ready(function () { console.log(1); });
$(document).ready(function () { console.log(2); });
```

Both functions will be called and the output will be both `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `$(document).ready(fn)` is a function provided by jQuery, which takes a function and adds it to a queue which gets executed when the document is ready.

On the other hand window.onLoad is a property on the window object, which gets called by the browser when the page is loaded. Therefore it gets overwritten if you access it twice. You may build something similar as the interface of `$(document).ready(fn)` if you do something like that:

```
window.onLoadQueue = []

window.onLoad = function() {
    window.onLoadQueue.forEach(function(fn) {
        fn()
    });
};

window.addOnLoad = function(fn) {
    // TODO: test if fn is a function
    window.onLoadQueue.push(fn);
}
```